# Text Element Effected By Document Flow When It Is Underneath

Tags: css

I have it where the blue element row overlaps. But for some reason, the bottom `div` text `foo` is being pushed still be the flow. Why is this? I expect `foo` to be on the left and not effected by the flow because of `z-index`.

[image]

```css
.goal-container {
  width: 900px;
}

.progress-column {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.goal-upper-well {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-color: @purple-blue;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.goal-lower-well {
  height: 300px;
  width: 700px;
  margin-top: -42px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.goal-upper {
  height: 43px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="goal-container">

  <div class="goal-upper">
    <div class="well well-sm goal-upper-well">
      <button type="button" class="btn-small expand-button"
        ng-click="isNavCollapsed = !isNavCollapsed"
        aria-label="Left Align">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      </button>
      Goal: {{goal.desc}}
    </div>
    <div class="progress-column">
      BARRRRRRRRRRR
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="goal-lower-well">
    <div class="well well-lg goal-lower-well">foo</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: z-index doesn't do anything as far as determining the rendering flow of the browser. It's primarily for determining the order in which things 'stack', or in which they receive focus when tabbing through elements. If you want to remove something from the rendering flow, you'd want to use position: absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have a negative top margin on your `foo` text. Just remove it and the `foo` text will go to the next line on the left.

```
.goal-lower-well {
  height: 300px;
  width: 700px;
  /* margin-top: -42px; */ Remove it
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You ned to clear the next 2 divs from floating

```css
.goal-container {
  width: 900px;
}

.progress-column {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.goal-upper-well {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-color: @purple-blue;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.goal-lower-well {
  clear: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 700px;
  margin-top: -42px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.goal-upper {
  height: 43px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="goal-container">

  <div class="goal-upper">
    <div class="well well-sm goal-upper-well">
      <button type="button" class="btn-small expand-button"
        ng-click="isNavCollapsed = !isNavCollapsed"
        aria-label="Left Align">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      </button>
      Goal: {{goal.desc}}
    </div>
    <div class="progress-column">
      BARRRRRRRRRRR
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="goal-lower-well">
    <div class="well well-lg goal-lower-well">foo</div>
  </div>

</div>
```